# CSS telescoping border animation on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to CSS animations and I'm having trouble animating border the way I want. Originally I wanted to have the left and right borders telescope from the center and meet with the top and bottom borders when the result-col element is hovered over.

I was able to figure out how to do it with the top and bottom borders, but I have them in separate divs, and gave them initial dimension.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xaranta/kjbsus96/1/)

```css
#case-results {
  background: #f6f5f0;
  padding: 0 0 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
}


.case-results-title hr{
  border: 1px solid #959a90;
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
}


.case-results-title i{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #787c74;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.result-col {
  color: #45474e;
}

.result-col:hover {
  color: #45474e;
}

.result-top {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 5px solid #959a90;
  border-left: 5px solid #959a90;
  border-right: 5px solid #959a90;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.result-col:hover .result-top {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  border-top: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  border-left: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  border-right: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  transition: .9s;
}

.result-bottom {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #959a90;
  border-left: 5px solid #959a90;
  border-right: 5px solid #959a90;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.result-col:hover .result-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  border-left: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  border-right: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  transition: .9s;
}

.result-txt {
  min-height: 210px;
    
}
.result-txt p{
    margin:0 0;
}
.result-col:hover .result-txt {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  border-left: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  border-right: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  transition-delay: .9s;
  /*transition: .5s;*/
}

.result-amount {
  font-size: 45px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.result-type {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.result-description {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="case-results">
     
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 result-col col-md-3">
                <div class="result-top"></div>
                <div class="result-txt">
                    <p class="result-amount">$100</p>
                    <p class="result-type">Settlement</p>
                    <p class="result-description">blah blah blah</p>
                </div>
                <div class="result-bottom"></div>
                </div>
      </div><!--/.row-->
     </div><!--/.container-->

    </section><!--/#case-results-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer might be animating the **min-height** property.

You have to set a min-height to de original state of your container (result-txt) and then make it bigger in the hover state.

With this you don't need the extra top and bottom div's.

```css
.case-results-title hr{
  border: 1px solid #959a90;
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
}


.case-results-title i{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #787c74;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.result-col {
  color: #45474e;
}

.result-col:hover {
  color: #45474e;
}

.result-txt {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
  border-top: 5px solid #959a90;
  border-left: 0px solid #959a90;
  border-right: 0px solid #959a90;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #959a90;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 40px;

  height: auto;
  min-height:20px;
}

.result-col:hover .result-txt {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  border-top: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  border-left: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  border-right: 5px solid #78a1bb;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  transition: .9s;


  min-height:200px;
}
.result-txt p{
    margin:0 0;
}
.result-col:hover .result-txt {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  border-left: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  border-right: 5px solid #78a1bb;
  transition-delay: .9s;
  /*transition: .5s;*/
}
.result-amount {
  font-size: 45px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.result-type {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.result-description {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
#case-results {
  background: #f6f5f0;
  padding: 0 0 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="case-results">
     
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 result-col col-md-3">
                
                <div class="result-txt">
                    <p class="result-amount">$100</p>
                    <p class="result-type">Settlement</p>
                    <p class="result-description">blah blah blah</p>
                </div>
                
                </div>
      </div><!--/.row-->
     </div><!--/.container-->

    </section><!--/#case-results-->
```